# Pyenv: Not able to install python 3.x version MacOS 12.3.1

Tags: python, macos, devops, pyenv

I am not able to I have tried to install different version of python3.9.X (3.9.8, 3.9.9, 3.9.10, 3.9.11) and none of them are working.
I have also tried some 3.8.X and 3.5.X all giving different errors.
I will post the 3.9.8 log (the one I am interested on)

```
 Platform information: MacOS Monterey 12.3.1
 pyenv version: 2.2.5
 Python version: 3.9.8
 C Compiler information: Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
 Command used in pyenv: pyenv install 3.9.8
```

This is my .zprofile (I am using oh-my-zsh)

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

I have also installed all the [required dependencies](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment)

```
brew install openssl readline sqlite3 xz zlib
```

Here you can find the [log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X4fnPkM-FMWUaREy5Ua2TqNu26UlRU_Y/view?usp=sharing) and here you can find the config [log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sS279WqvomsH4wlU_7t_Qc7TC97c6cmU/view?usp=sharing)

This is what I am getting:

```
@ pyenv install 3.9.8
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.9.8.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.8/Python-3.9.8.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.9.8...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.2.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/jl/hp_s9knj13x5ft7mffr258r40000gp/T/python-build.20220412182145.25030
Results logged to /var/folders/jl/hp_s9knj13x5ft7mffr258r40000gp/T/python-build.20220412182145.25030.log

Last 10 log lines:
if test $? -ne 0 ; then \
    echo "generate-posix-vars failed" ; \
    rm -f ./pybuilddir.txt ; \
    exit 1 ; \
fi
make: *** [Makefile:688: python.exe-gdb.py] Killed: 9
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/bin/sh: line 5: 33970 Killed: 9               ./python.exe -E -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars
generate-posix-vars failed
make: *** [Makefile:618: pybuilddir.txt] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a couple of days with the issue and I found the answer on the GitHub Issues.

**The problem was the antivirus** as documented [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2248).

Once the Antivirus was disabled everything was installed without any error (I tried python 3.9.8, 3.9.9, 3.9.10, 3.9.11). I had Apex One (Mac) Antivirus and uninstalling was not trivial.
[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/350748/how-do-i-uninstall-trend-micro-security-agent?newreg=5331ec399f2b4b69821434b42ab18eda) guide was helpful.
 
 I used Those two commands:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.trendmicro.* /Library/LaunchAgents/com.trendmicro.*
sudo kill -9 $(pgrep iCoreService TmLoginMgr)
```

If you recieve this warning is completly fine

```
Warning: Expecting a LaunchDaemons path since the command was ran as root. Got LaunchAgents instead.
`launchctl bootout` is a recommended alternative.
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.trendmicro.TmLoginMgr.plist: Could not find specified service
Unload failed: 113: Could not find specified service
```

Just check your Icon on the top bar is gone. 
 Additionally you can make sure this command does not return any process:

```
pgrep iCoreService TmLoginMgr MainUI
```

Comment: "The problem was the antivirus" doesn't sound insane at all.